# Quadratic Formula - Error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++

I got this error:

> Error 1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

on line:

```
discr=((pow(b, 2))-4(a*c));
```

Code for Quadratic formula program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
using namespace std;
float a, b, c, d,x1, x2, discr;
int ec2g(float a, float b, float c, float & x1, float & x2);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout<<"'a'"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"'b'"<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"'c'"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    if (ec2g(a, b, c, x1, x2)){
        cout<<x1<<x2<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"No solution"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
} 

int ec2g(float a, float b, float c, float & x1, float & x2){
int solreal=0;
discr=((pow(b, 2))-4(a*c));
if(discr>0.0){
solreal=1;
x1=(-b+sqrt(discr)/(2.0*a));
x2=(-b-sqrt(discr)/(2.0*a));
}
return solreal;
}
```

any idea of how can I fix this?

Comment: First get rid of all the parentheses except the ones for the call to `pow`; they're not needed. After those distractions are gone the problem should be obvious.

Comment: Your global variables should all be local variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to multiply.  And so the compiler thought it looked like a function call.

```
4*(a*c)
 ^
```

As a side note, you shouldn't need `pow` either.  Just do:

```
discr = b * b - 4.0f * a * c;
```